# Javascript list files and tell if they are a file or a directory

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a javascript file manager and I want to list all my files in the home directory and know if they are files or directories, here's the code:

```
var listFiles = function (path) {
    var files = fs.readdirSync(HOME);

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var name = HOME + '/' + files[i];

        fs.stat(name.toString(), function (err, fileStat) {
            if(fileStat.isFile()){
                console.log(name.toString() + ' -> FILE');
            }
            else if (fileStat.isDirectory()) {
                console.log(name.toString() + ' -> DIR');
            }
        });
    }
};

var HOME = '/home/user'
var local = listFiles(HOME);
```

And the output is something like this:

```
/home/user/.xsession-errors.old -> DIR
/home/user/.xsession-errors.old -> FILE
/home/user/.xsession-errors.old -> DIR
/home/user/.xsession-errors.old -> DIR
/home/user/.xsession-errors.old -> FILE
/home/user/.xsession-errors.old -> FILE
/home/user/.xsession-errors.old -> FILE
/home/user/.xsession-errors.old -> DIR
/home/user/.xsession-errors.old -> DIR
/home/user/.xsession-errors.old -> FILE
```

The problem is that I only get

`/home/user/.xsession-errors.old -> FILE (or DIR)`

as file's name and not the expected one (e.g.: /home/user/file.txt)

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: as name of the file I only get /home/user/.xsession-errors.old -> FILE (or DIR), and not the real file name

Comment: Have you tried using https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options for reading the home directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that at the time the callback is called, `name` contains the name of the last file. You should learn about how variable scope works in JavaScript.

This [MDN article on closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) might help.

This could do it:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var listFiles = function (basepath) {
    fs.readdirSync(basepath).forEach(function (filename) {
        var fullpath = path.join(basepath, filename);

         fs.stat(fullpath, function (err, fileStat) {
            if (fileStat.isFile()) {
                console.log(filename + ' -> FILE');
            } else if (fileStat.isDirectory()) {
                console.log(filename + ' -> DIR');
            }
        });

    });
};
```